# Reset bash history search position

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

In a terminal the Bash history can be searched easily with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>. But what if I cannot find what I am looking for? I am stuck in the middle of my history. What if a want to search again from the beginning?

Is there another shortcut to reset the history search?

Comment: You could use a command line tool called fzf (fuzzy finder). With it you don't need to remember the entire command and by choosing (or not) the command you don't run it, instead you just display it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is <kbd>Meta</kbd> + <kbd>></kbd>, which is bound to `end-of-history` and useful if you're in the middle of your history. The meta key is usually the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

If you see that your incremental history search isn't successful, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>, which is bound to `abort` and restores the previous line and history position.

Check the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Miscellaneous-Commands) for more commands like these.

Comment: What is the difference, between end-of-history and abort?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I think `end-of-history` moves the history position to the end of history, no matter where you are currently; `abort` resets it to where you were before starting an incremental search, which might not necessarily be the end.

Answer (score 10):

This may be a somewhat indirect answer, but I usually use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to exit the history search. This cancels your entire line entry, leaving you on a fresh prompt with no input on the line, and back at the end of the history list.

Comment: OK, checked that. Even if you did not use Ctrl+c to terminate the search and find yourself in the middle of your history you can always do Ctrl+r followed by Ctrl+c to get back to the end of your history. Not perfect, but it works.

Comment: Or just plain Ctrl+C.