# Alternative to Ctrl-R reverse search in bash

Tags: bash, readline

I am happy and really like the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> backward search feature of the bash shell. Some of my colleagues don't like it, since it is sometimes confusing. I understand them. If you enter the wrong characters, the current position in the history is somewhere in the past, and you won't find the recent matches.

Is there a more user friendly alternative for seaching backward in the shell history?

I want to stick with bash. Suggesting an alternative shell is not an answer to this question.

The issue with the "lost position" is explained here: [Reset bash history search position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34793704/reset-bash-history-search-position) These solutions work. That's right. But the solution there are not easy and user friendly according to my point of view. These solutions are not simple and straight forward. These are solutions of the past. In the past the human needed to learn the way the computer wanted the input. But today the tools should accept the input in a way which is easy for the user.

Comment: Configuration and use of an interactive shell is a topic for [unix.se], not Stack Overflow; our scope here is limited to questions "unique to software development".

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you are right. I opened a new question there: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/523543/alternative-to-ctrl-r-reverse-search-in-bash

Answer (score 2):

If you type the wrong characters to search for, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> to stop the search and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> and the correct characters to restart the search.

You can also set up <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> to reverse the direction of the search in case you entered the correct search characters but went to many steps backward. The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> allows you to go forward. To enable this, you will need to add:

```
stty -ixon
```

to your Bash startup file.

That command turns off the default [flow control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_flow_control) function of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> and makes those key combinations available for other uses. In Bash by default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> is used for history search and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> is a duplicate of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> which performs quoted insert (e.g. pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> results in `^M` being inserted as a representation for the single character for Return).

And you might need to add:

```
"\C-s": forward-search-history
```

to your `~/.inputrc`.

Comment: Note that `ctrl-S` and `ctrl-Q` are also used by most terminals for flow control (ctrl-S is pause) so you might want to use a different key.

Comment: @GemTaylor: The command `stty -ixon` in my answer turns off flow control.

Comment: Good to explain this :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `history-search-backward`. It's not bound to any key by default, so you need to add

```
"\eq": history-search-backward
```

to your `~/.inputrc`. Then you can type a prefix of the command you want to find in the history, e.g.

```
cd /l
```

then press <kbd>Alt+q</kbd> and the shell will expand it to

```
cd /last-visited-dir
```

Pressing the key combination again will search for a previous mention, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Piping `history` through `grep` gives you a "less interactive" way to interface with the history buffer, but sometimes less interactive is what you need.

You can re-execute a specific numbered command from the grep output with `!number`